# Why Route Error Send POST data "in RouteCollection.php (line 251)"

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes

im setting up new route that send data POST to my Controller, same POST method but not working

im using laravel 5.4

my route code :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'newsletter'], function () {
        Route::get('/', ['as' => 'newsletter.generate', 'uses' => 'Newsletter\GenerateController@index']);
        Route::get('details/{id}', ['as' => 'newsletter.details', 'uses' => 'Newsletter\GenerateController@show']);         
        Route::post('details/{id}/sendNewsletter', ['as' => 'newsletter.sendNewsletter', 'uses' => 'Newsletter\GenerateController@sendNewsletter']);
        Route::get('report', ['as' => 'newsletter.report', 'uses' => 'Newsletter\ReportController@index']);
    });
```

my blade code :

```
 <form action="{{ route('newsletter.sendNewsletter', ['id' => request()->route('id')]) }}" method="POST" id="user-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group row"> <label class="col-sm-2 form-control-label">Subjek</label>
<div class="col-sm-8"> <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="No" required></div>
```

output always error "(1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
in RouteCollection.php (line 251)"

Comment: Close the `<form>` tag and as far as I see you are missing `@csrf` token in your form.

Comment: ohh i got another form inside form i made before, like form 'PUT' method inside form 'POST' method, thanks @nakov !

Answer (score 0):

my code error because, there is another form with 'PUT' method inside my form with 'POST' method, make laravel route confuse to choose method data